# The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found on Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

After accidentally deleting a project via the Source Control area of VSCode Omnisharp stopped working altogether. Nothing works on any previous project and any newly created projects. Everything works just fine on Visual Studio so I assume the problem isn't with the .NET Core installation. I'm on a Mac.

[image]

```
    "message": "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [API, API, API]"
```

What I've tried:

- Reinstall .Net Core 3.1 (without uninstalling it first)
- Completely delete VSCode (including hidden directories, caches, everything)
- Easier solutions found around the web such as rebuild, restart omnisharp, etc.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The Core library is a single library while in Net each library has its own namespace (dll).  If you go into VS : Solution Explorer and look at the libraries under reference they shold always be the same as the using statements at top of module.  A core project you will see in the references System.Core and the using statement should be the same.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure if this helps, since the project is working fine on Visual Studio but not on Visual Studio Code

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies

Comment: @jdweng If it's an assembly issue, why is it working on Visual Studio? :(

Comment: The libraries are packaged differently in Net (what you are calling VS) and in Core.  The libraries are dll and you use a different dlls in a core application than a net application.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 7):

Following these [steps](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3990#issuecomment-675227919) helped me to solve the issue:

```
 * Go to the VSCode settings (File > Preferences > Settings).
 * Search with the keywords omnisharp use global mono to locate the configuration.
 * Change the value to never from either auto or always.
 * REMEMBER to restart the VSCode to activate the change (I restarted it twice to be sure).
```